# How to make a div the size of its content, while the content has no line-break?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a `div` which has the width of my screen. It has `overflow: scroll`. In this div I have `0-n` other divs which can have varying widths.

I want my div to grow with its content, so I can simply scroll horizontal. However, my div just grows in height, and its content just stacks vertically. `display: inline-block` doesnt work on the content.

How can I solve this Problem?

P.S: It works if I set a fixed width to my div, of course this is too wide or too small most of the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly add your code snippet here.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GRBc6/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mixture of `inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap`:

```css
.parent {
    white-space:nowrap; /* make children all on one line */
    width:100%; 
    overflow:auto;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block; /* make inline block so obeys parent's white space */
    white-space: normal; /* reset white space for children */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
    <div class="child">lots of text and stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

If you don't want to define a width, you can use jQuery for that. How? Like this

```js
var width = $('.child').width();;
$('.inner .child').each(function() { width += $(this).width(); });
$('.inner').css('width', width)
```

```css
 .child{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    .parent{
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```